# Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.10 to 20.04 LTS from command line

Tags: command-line, 20.04, package-management, 18.10, do-release-upgrade

I have Ubuntu 18.10 and want to update to 20.04 LTS but after this standard procedure:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

But when I execute the last command I got this: `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.`

I noticed that when I upgrade I got this: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.`

I can't complete the upgrade because I have some 404, can someone help me about this issue? I am really rusty with this OS and i surely don't want to uninstall and reinstall!

Comment: The *fully QA tested* and supported path from 18.10 was to the next release, ie. 18.10 to 19.04, from 19.04 to 19.10, then from 19.10 to 20.04.  You however have missed that path; as upgrade tools will **not** upgrade you to an EOL release.  An *upgrade via re-install* would now be the recommended way; as skipping releases can have unintended consequences (you'll have to do the homework yourself as it's an unsupported path).  Yes CI testing occurs for all paths; but that checks package upgrades; not for user-data (your job).

Comment: Ubuntu offers two upgrade paths, (1) upgrade via every release as I described in the prior comment, or (2) upgrade from one LTS to the next LTS (ie. skip releases between the LTS), however you are not on that skip path as you're not using a LTS. You've not said if desktop or server, but if desktop; *upgrade via re-install* is super-fast & easy...

Comment: Since you are using a very old unsupported release, I would think that you are not using this system extensively or it is not critical. I would suggest a _reinstallation_ with the latest LTS release (20.04).

Comment: Another thought; 18.10 was the last release that had ISOs released in *i386* (or x86 32-bit); so whilst ISOs were created into the *alpha* stage with *i386*, if your system is in fact *i386*, the only way forward for you is backwards; ie. the last *i386* release that is still supported is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (again *upgrade via re-install* is the easiest way to go, esp. if desktop; select existing partitions & do **not** format any, and no user file is touched, all *user-installed* Ubuntu packages will be re-installed if available in new release (from Ubuntu repositories)

Comment: @guiverc, I wonder if you would consider converting your points into an answer? The upgrade paths offered and recommendation to upgrade via reinstall is very useful in my opinion.

Comment: @Will, I've not said anything here I've not said elsewhere on this site probably 30+ times.  I'm a big fan of the *upgrade via re-install* method, which allows *skipping* releases, re-installing the same release (*after we've stuffed something up*) & even going backwards (though it can have *pitfalls*) and I QA-test it rather often... If you'll benefit from it I will, but I personally don't see a need.  I provide support, and don't upgrade those boxes; just *upgrade via re-install* as its a QA-test knocked off & takes only slightly longer then the `full-upgrade` anyway (mostly recording QA)

Comment: The problem explained in body of the question does not match the title. The problem in the body is that the 18.10 repositories have been closed, and solving that problem is clearly explained in the duplicate link. Advice: @guiverc is right -- back up your data and install a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc - thanks, no need then - I'll be guided by you. It's not a problem I envisage having as I'm sticking with LTS and would reinstall as suggested, but I liked how succinct your answers were and thought they'd help others - but if it's all there in answers already then I'm sure you're right not to clutter the site with duplicate answers.

Comment: Of the 30+, many of them would be in comments (or deleted questions/answers), but key is don't format (ie. *something else*.  It works well with desktop installs; as packages installed are noted, system directories are wiped, new install done, then install done, then restore of additional packages (if available).  (this install type triggered by no-format). As desktop app configs are stored in $HOME (user directory) none are touched.. Alas many server apps store configs in system directories, thus restore of config files is necessary for server installs  (it's great though on desktop installs)